Find a non-zero holomorphic 1 form on an almost complex manifold
Let $(M,J)$ be an almost complex manifold and $\phi:M\to\mathbb{R}$ a non-constant function which satisfies $dJd(\phi)=0$, where $Jd\phi$ is the 1-form given by $TM\ni v\mapsto d\phi(Jv)$. Prove that $M$ admits a non-zero holomorphic 1-form.
I tried to check that $d\phi+Jd\phi$ is complex-linear, but no success.

For the sake of clarity, what is meant here as a holomorphic $1$-form? I could guess that it is a $(1,0)$ form $\eta$ such that the $(1,1)$-part of $d\eta$ vanishes, but I could be wrong as the manifold is just assumed to be almost-complex.

A holomorphic 1-form is a holomorphic section of $\Omega^{1,0}$, where $\Omega^1=\Omega^{1,0}\oplus\Omega^{0,1}$ is the decomposition induced by $J$. That means that holomorphic 1-forms are in the $\sqrt{-1}$-eigenspace of $J$, which is what I meant by "complex-linear", namely $\omega(Jv)=\sqrt{-1}\omega(v)$.

Is that equivalent to the vanishing of the $(1,1)$ part of $d\omega$? I believe what I wrote is well-defined for almost-complex manifolds in general.

Being "complex-linear" in that sense guarantees that $\omega$ is a section of $\Omega^{1,0}$, my question was to clarify in which sense a section of $\Omega^{1,0}$ can be holomorphic in the almost-complex case. In the complex situation for example every holomorphic bundle has a natural $\bar{\partial}$-operator and this operator can be used to that a section $\omega$ is holomorphic iff $\bar{\partial}\omega=0$. I guess in the almost complex case there might be other, non-equivalent notions (but I am not sure).
